# I cant seem to figure out FCC or any testing for that matter

Tags: fcc, production-testing, compliance

this website has a wealth of information and after browsing for quite a while I cant seem to answer my question. I am interested in selling an LED PCB light in the US. It operates on 24v1amp DC powersupply and the light has a total wattage of 20watts. It also has a dimmer with temperature control. The dimmer just so happens to also emit a few RF frequencies for wireless controll which I actually dont need. Its says it has these optional output frequencies: 0.5K、1K、2K、4K、8K.

So my question is I have a very niche market maybe 100 of these products per year. So obviously 20,000$ of testing is simply way out of the question.

I'll be honest what do I need to do to sell this product with no testing!?

The powersupply 24v1a switching powersupply. Is it legally required to have FCC.

The Dimmer with the RF frequencies must have FCC approval?

And finally the LED pcb board does it need any testing?

Secondly, The Dimmer actually may already have FCC approval from china im not sure if it is legit though(Ill have to investigate that further).. IF it is approved do I still need to test the entire system for FCC approval or is it sufficient just to have FCC testing on the dimmer. Basically I am interested in the cheapest possible method of selling this low margin low volume product to a few of my friends in interest clubs.

**edit:**

I would like to ask about the verification. From what I have read my product needs just FCC verification. And this can be completed by any testing facility in the US or foreign country with good standard of practice I believe?

Comment: If you can't get ROI to pay back the development cost, then it's not a viable product. If you want to do this the formally correct way, then you are screwed.

Comment: How so any explanation?

Comment: Which pieces Absolutely need FCC approval. Because I will just remove those from the package.

Comment: Yeah, well - you kinda said it yourself. I don't know the FCC rules, only the European ones, but if you plan to manufacture or sell equipment that is required to have FCC approval, then you will have to do some testing anyway. You might get away with easier tests by using pre-approved power supplies and sub-systems, but as long as you have added any custom hardware then I would be surprised if you got off without having to test at all.

Comment: I think there are some rules for selling kits that omits the testing, but I don't know the exact requirements. The FCC would be the correct contact point for that information, I guess.

Comment: That being said, I don't think the chance that government will notice your low volume product is very significant, so there is always the possibility to just not give a shit. Not that I will recommend that in any way, of course

Comment: Ya thats basically what Im trying to find out is which of the above parts actually are legally required to be FCC approved:

Comment: These parts are: a 2v 1a wall plug AC/DC powersupply, A dimmer knob that also has the RF frequencies .5-8k, and an LED PCB board with 20w of leds basically a recessed light. Do All PCB boards require testing? I really know nothing about this.

Comment: Another thing I have read is that the frequency range for intentional radiator is 9k-30mhz and my dimmer is only at a max of 7k frequency emitter so it is considered an unintentional emmitter?

Comment: "The dimmer just so happens to also emit a few RF frequencies for wireless controll which I actually dont need. Its says it has these optional output frequencies: 0.5K、1K、2K、4K、8K."  these are audio frequencies, not RF. If the device doesn't have an RF _transmitter_ in it then it is an 'unintentional' radiator.

Comment: Hmm I see shows how much I know haha. So then the entire device is an unintentional radiator but still needs FCC approval?

Comment: At least that helps me a lot knowing that it is far less expensive to test for unintentional radiators.

Comment: I guess Im a little confused because the remote(which I would not use is called an RF remote but the dimmer states its frequencies are 0.5K、1K、2K、4K、8K.) probably need to read up on how that actually works.

Comment: "The dimmer just so happens to also emit a few RF frequencies for wireless controll" - I don't know about the FCC, but in my country any device that *intentionally* transmits radio waves must be tested and certified, whereas products that don't intentionally transmit don't need as extensive testing under certain conditions. So you might want to scrap the wireless control.

Comment: (Also, as previously stated, those are not RF frequencies. You don't even seem to know what the device you are selling *does*!)

Comment: Well Im not an engineer just interested in selling a product. I also didnt design the PCB and assemble it...

Comment: Another noteworthy point is that if everyone else on the market can figure it out, so can you.

Comment: Is this it? [Wall mount led lighting controller](https://wholesaler.alibaba.com/product-detail/K1-12V-24V-Wall-mount-led_60664553273.html) "Optional **output** frequency 0.5K,1K, 2K, 4K, 8K" - nothing about RF here. "**compatible with** T series wireless remote control". If your dimmer comes bundled with an RF remote that is not FCC approved then just throw the remote away - problem solved!

Answer (score 2):

Compliance is not trivial. If you do not have the resources or knowledge to form a basic compliance plan, you cannot hope to pass any certification requirements. The FCC is not responsible for helping you with this process. You have to show them why/how your product complies with the applicable regulations. Determining the applicability of regulations can require minute attention to the details of the design. We do not have enough information to tell you which regulations are applicable without seeing all of the descriptive, controlled data that defines it. We would also have to review things like your manufacturing process to ensure that there are no process-related concerns that could affect in-service noncompliance.

If you're serious about this, you should consider hiring a Certification Engineer who knows how to do it. Depending on how much you value your time and sanity, that may well be the cheaper alternative.

Alternatively, you can start reading the regulations themselves along with their associated guidance materials. Be warned, this is a *career*. Start here:47 CFR 15
https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=6d3d77d9dbd8f9fa37744461b91d1dbe&mc=true&tpl=/ecfrbrowse/Title47/47cfr15_main_02.tpl

Comment: This by the way is a fine definition of how regulation stifles productivity.

Comment: All regulations exist for a reason. Electromagnetic pollution is pollution. If you produce and sell a device, it can't be allowed to pollute significantly. Would it be easier for companies of any kind to sell their products without regulation? Yes. Would it result in increased pollution? Yes. Regulatory compliance is important in formal professional engineering practice, as in any other.

Comment: Maybe, but regulation also tends to be heavily influenced by big industry players who can afford large compliance departments, lawyers etc. It helps keep the man in a shed out of the marketplace, or force him to sell to an already existing large company. One could argue that the internet should have been fiercely regulated from the start and if so, it would never have flourished, because two guys in a dorm room with an idea would have been defeated by the compliance costs to prove their "Google" should be allowed to exist. It is very debatable whether all regulations exist for a reason.

Comment: I agree its good and bad. But there should be more flexibility for startups.

Comment: It's difficult, but regulatory agencies cannot give special treatment based on economic situations. It is irrelevant to compliance.

Comment: In my case I am trying to produce a product that does not need FCC testing. I need to know how much I need to simplify it even if its all the way down to just selling the aluminum casing with ZERO electronics. So I guess the best option would be to work my way up from there.

Comment: Seems to me all that I need is a Supplier’s Declaration of Conformity (DoC)

Comment: I will add that it seems to me that a startup could afford to be less paranoid about meeting regulations as they have less to lose. (You'd still want to be 99% sure that your device meets regulations - but you wouldn't need to be 99.99999999999% sure)

Comment: @IanBland It's not really, certification is around $5-10K for most products. That's chump change if you're hoping to make a living out of selling a product to mass market, but is hopefully enough to stop idiots making broadband RF transmitters widely available. I don't disagree that large established companies have an influence on regulations, but that's the advantage of being large and there first!

Comment: Not necessarily; it's not chump change for (for instance) a small production run of some specialised enthusiast product. On a production run of 10,000, that's costs of $1 per product which will reflect considerably higher in the final price. Use my prior analogy; imagine if you had to stump up 10 grand up front to set up a website. How many would that discourage? Would we even have the web under those conditions?

Comment: @IanBland 1) If it's a small run enthusiast product, your client base is likely to be elastic to a $1 cost. Do you mind paying $1 more for an excellent small batch beer over a Bud (or whatever your poison is), for example? If your product is successful, then that cost is amortised even further. 2) Not a relevant comparison: a website has near zero external consequence if it's bad, and zero cost to revoke. An RF transmitter can cause service loss or degradation and also would require physical activity to remedy; neither is cheap.

Comment: Actually websites are criticised for all kinds of things like distributing malware, giving dangerous information to terrorists, destroying public morals... all of which are used to argue for regulation. As to costs, a £1 on costs is probably £5 on price. If you're selling 1000 units potentially, that's £50 on the price, and  you need to pay it up front. So you have to borrow...

Comment: @IanBland 1st point stands: the revocation cost of a website is near zero and it's instantaneous and global. Contrast that to collecting 1000+ defective units. Personally, I wouldn't pass on the full amount of an amortising cost to the price. It's just part of the business plan. I agree there's a lot of silly regs; EMI regulation is not one of them.

Comment: I'm not talking about whether the regs are silly, I was merely indicating the impact of them.